# Should I prefer rendering layout at run time or Include it in XML layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, viewrendering

I need to show a "**No data found**" message on many screens in my app. For that I created a separate layout with message and image; Now,I'm not sure whether I should include that layout in all other activities' layout or render this layout at runtime? What would be more efficient? Any suggestion is appreciable.

Thanks;

Comment: read this [Dynamic vs XML layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11960645/5305430)

Comment: Thanks, Sushil. My concern is still not clear, do you have any personal opinion on this?

Comment: As you deleted the answer posted by you. I'm saddened by the thought that people are actually here just for earning reputation points rather than genuinely resolving a problem.  @SushilKumar

Comment: I already given your 2-3 solution but non work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use a textview with text : "No data found" in all layouts and set VISIBILITY GONE or VISIBLE according to api result. 
Or you can add view to your main layout if no data found. Like this;

```
public showAlert(LinearLayout layout){
    TextView textView= new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("No data found");
    layout.addView(textView);
}
```

Write this function in a class and call everywhere you want

Comment: I can do the same thing but I want to reduce the redundancy as much as I can and want to keep my code efficient. That's all :)

Comment: You can reuse the xml file, but what about the visibility condition?

Comment: that is not the concern that can be done. The problem lies in, in which way it should be done